How to fix repeated use of BRepAlgoAPI_Fuse issues?
I am writing some code in Python using OCC that takes a list of gp_Pnt points and then starting at the tip makes a cone followed by a whole bunch of cylinders fused with spheres one after another to create a needle channel type shape. I have been struggling to find a reason as to why this is happening, but it seems that occasionally there are errors in the completed channel. For example in my first picture as shown here on the right it seems that a component was missed, but I don't believe I could have missed a point between 2 points the way things are coded so am confused as to why this is not working. Also, on some of the shapes it seams as though the cylinder is not fully forming. I suspect that I have misused BRepAlgoAPI_Fuse or perhaps BRepOffsetAPI_MakePipe somehow. If anyone is able to help I would be very appreciative, thank you. (---Update---, I have not yet solved the problem but if you scroll past to the update section I have added a simplified version of the problem)
If there is any more information that might be helpful to solve the problem please let me know, if I find the solution in the meanwhile I will post the solution to the issue. I have tried to take irrelevant pieces of code out of the issue
enter image description here
    channel_points = np.array(channel_points)

    channel_points[:,2] += offset

    # Number of decimal places to keep
    decimals = 2

    # Truncate without rounding
    channel_points = np.floor(channel_points * 10**decimals) / 10**decimals

    points = [gp_Pnt(point[0], point[1], point[2]) for point in channel_points]

    radius = diameter / 2

    p1 = points[0]
    p2 = points[1]
    length = helper.get_magnitude(p1, p2)
    vector = helper.get_vector(p1, p2, length=TIP_LENGTH) #gives normalized vector if p2-p1 *TIP_LENGTH
    p_mid = gp_Pnt(p1.X() + vector.X(), p1.Y() +
                       vector.Y(), p1.Z() + vector.Z())
    cone = _cone_pipe(p1, p_mid, radius) #makes cone at end of needle
    pipe = _rounded_pipe(p_mid, p2, radius)
    if pipe:
        print("Channel")
    pipe = BRepAlgoAPI_Fuse(cone, pipe).Shape()
        

    # rest of the points
    for i in range(1, len(points) - 1):
        p1 = points[i]
        p2 = points[i + 1]
        #print("("+str(p1.X())+","+str(p1.Y())+","+str(p1.Z())+")")
        cylinder = _rounded_pipe(p1, p2, radius)
        try:
            tempfuse = BRepAlgoAPI_Fuse(pipe, cylinder)
            if tempfuse.HasWarnings():
                print(i,"Error")
            pipe = tempfuse.Shape()
        except:
            print("Error2")

    return pipe

    def _cone_pipe(p1, p2, radius: float) -> TopoDS_Shape:
        length = helper.get_magnitude(p1, p2) #gives vector p2 - p1 and then get the norm
        direction = helper.get_direction(p1, p2) #gives normalised p2-p1 vector
        axis = gp_Ax2(p1, direction) # creates coordinate system with an origin at p1, and z- axis pointed in "direction" (referes to z-axis as main direction I believe)
        return BRepPrimAPI_MakeCone(axis, 0.0, radius, length).Shape() # Cone made with height = length, bottom radius = 0, top radius =radius, on the axis as defined in the previous line

    def _rounded_pipe(p1: gp_Pnt, p2: gp_Pnt, radius: float) -> TopoDS_Shape:
        direction = helper.get_direction(p1, p2) #gives normalised p2-p1 vector
        profile = helper.circle_profile(p1, direction, radius) # cirlce centered at p1, orientated with up as direction and having a raius of radius. The face of the circle is given here
        guide_edge = BRepBuilderAPI_MakeEdge(p1, p2).Edge()
        guide_wire = BRepBuilderAPI_MakeWire(guide_edge).Wire()


        cylinder = BRepOffsetAPI_MakePipe(guide_wire, profile).Shape() #I believe this makes the cylinder the around the "guild_wire" (which is just a line from p1 to p2) using the circle shape (profile) as the radius
        sphere = BRepPrimAPI_MakeSphere(p2, radius).Shape()# makes a sphere centered at p2 and then makes it radius = radius
        #sphere1 = BRepPrimAPI_MakeSphere(p1, radius).Shape()
        tempfusedpipe = BRepAlgoAPI_Fuse(cylinder, sphere)
        # tempfusedpipe2 = BRepAlgoAPI_Fuse(tempfusedpipe, sphere1)
        return tempfusedpipe.Shape() # adds cylinder an sphere together

also these are the relevant functions from the helper file I am using
def get_direction(p1: gp_Pnt, p2: gp_Pnt) -> gp_Dir:
    vector = get_vector(p1, p2) #p2-p1*length where p2 and p1 are vectors and length is 1 by default
    return gp_Dir(vector.X(), vector.Y(), vector.Z()) #gives normalized vector

def circle_profile(origin: gp_Pnt, direction: gp_Vec, radius: float) -> TopoDS_Face:
    circle = gp_Circ(gp_Ax2(origin, direction), radius) #makes circle in 3D space oriented upwards with radius = radius
    edge = BRepBuilderAPI_MakeEdge(circle).Edge()       #I believe this returns the edge of the circle
    wire = BRepBuilderAPI_MakeWire(edge).Wire()         #Makes wire from edge where a wire is just a line that will be used later
    return BRepBuilderAPI_MakeFace(wire).Face()         #Makes circle face from wire

def get_magnitude(p1: gp_Pnt, p2: gp_Pnt) -> float:
    vector = np.array([p2.X(), p2.Y(), p2.Z()]) \
        - np.array([p1.X(), p1.Y(), p1.Z()])
    return np.linalg.norm(vector)#np.linalg.norm (defaults to 2-norm)

def get_direction(p1: gp_Pnt, p2: gp_Pnt) -> gp_Dir:
    vector = get_vector(p1, p2) #p2-p1*length where p2 and p1 are vectors and length is 1 by default
    return gp_Dir(vector.X(), vector.Y(), vector.Z()) #gives normalized vector

def get_vector(p1: gp_Pnt, p2: gp_Pnt, length: float = 1.0) -> gp_Vec:
    vector = gp_Vec(
        p2.X() - p1.X(),
        p2.Y() - p1.Y(),
        p2.Z() - p1.Z())
    return vector.Normalized() * length

Also, here are the packages I am using in the 2 folders of the project I am working on
from OCC.Core.BRepAdaptor import BRepAdaptor_Surface
from OCC.Core.BRepAlgoAPI import BRepAlgoAPI_Fuse
from OCC.Core.BRepBuilderAPI import BRepBuilderAPI_MakeEdge, BRepBuilderAPI_MakeWire, BRepBuilderAPI_MakeFace
from OCC.Core.BRepPrimAPI import BRepPrimAPI_MakePrism, BRepPrimAPI_MakeCone, BRepPrimAPI_MakeSphere
from OCC.Core.BRepOffsetAPI import BRepOffsetAPI_MakePipe
from OCC.Core.GeomAbs import GeomAbs_Plane
from OCC.Core.Geom import Geom_BezierCurve
from OCC.Core.TopAbs import TopAbs_FACE
from OCC.Core.TopExp import TopExp_Explorer
from OCC.Core.TopoDS import topods, TopoDS_Face, TopoDS_Shape
from OCC.Core.TColgp import TColgp_Array1OfPnt
from OCC.Core.gp import gp_Dir, gp_Ax2, gp_Pnt, gp_Pln, gp_Vec, gp_Circ
from OCC.Extend.ShapeFactory import translate_shp, rotate_shape

Again, if anyone is able to help thank you very much in advance
I have also tried using
# tempfuse = BRepAlgoAPI_Fuse(pipe, cylinder).SetFuzzyValue(0.00005)

and I have also tried to narrow down the issue with
tempfuse.HasWarnings()

to narrow down what is causing the issue, but have not been super successful as of yet. Playing with the number of decimals has fixed some similar issues, but I do not know what is truly causing the problem
I have tried reading some of the information on BRepAlgoAPI_Fuse on https://dev.opencascade.org/doc/occt-6.9.1/refman/html/class_b_rep_algo_a_p_i___fuse.html but have not had much success
-




-----UPDATE-----:






I have simplified the problem somewhat to the following code if anyone is able to help based on this update I would be very appreciative
from OCC.Core.BRepAlgoAPI import BRepAlgoAPI_Fuse
from OCC.Core.BRepBuilderAPI import BRepBuilderAPI_Transform
from OCC.Core.gp import gp_Vec, gp_Trsf
from OCC.Core.BRepPrimAPI import BRepPrimAPI_MakeCylinder, BRepPrimAPI_MakeTorus
from OCC.Core.gp import gp_Trsf
from OCC.Core.TopTools import TopTools_ListOfShape
from OCC.Display.SimpleGui import init_display

from OCC.Core.gp import gp_Pnt, gp_Ax2, gp_Dir
from OCC.Core.BRepPrimAPI import BRepPrimAPI_MakeCone, BRepPrimAPI_MakeSphere, BRepPrimAPI_MakeCylinder
from OCC.Core.TopoDS import TopoDS_Shape
from OCC.Core.TopTools import TopTools_ListOfShape

import numpy as np

display, start_display, add_menu, add_function_to_menu = init_display(size=(1500,1000))
display.EraseAll()

def printpoint(p1: gp_Pnt):
    print("("+str(p1.X())+","+str(p1.Y())+","+str(p1.Z())+")")

def get_vector(p1: gp_Pnt, p2: gp_Pnt, length: float = 1.0) -> gp_Vec:
    vector = gp_Vec(
        p2.X() - p1.X(),
        p2.Y() - p1.Y(),
        p2.Z() - p1.Z())
    return vector.Normalized() * length

def get_direction(p1: gp_Pnt, p2: gp_Pnt) -> gp_Dir:
    vector = get_vector(p1, p2) #p2-p1*length where p2 and p1 are vectors and length is 1 by default
    return gp_Dir(vector.X(), vector.Y(), vector.Z()) #gives normalized vector

def get_magnitude(p1: gp_Pnt, p2: gp_Pnt) -> float:
    vector = np.array([p2.X(), p2.Y(), p2.Z()]) \
        - np.array([p1.X(), p1.Y(), p1.Z()])
    return np.linalg.norm(vector)#np.linalg.norm (defaults to 2-norm)

def _rounded_pipe(p1: gp_Pnt, p2: gp_Pnt, radius: float) -> TopoDS_Shape:
    direction = get_direction(p1, p2) #gives normalised p2-p1 vector
    length = get_magnitude(p1,p2)

    spheret = BRepPrimAPI_MakeSphere(p2, radius).Shape()# makes a sphere centered at p2 and then makes its radius = radius
    #sphereb = BRepPrimAPI_MakeSphere(p1, radius).Shape()# makes a sphere centered at p2 and then makes its radius = radius
    cylinder = BRepPrimAPI_MakeCylinder(gp_Ax2(p1, direction), radius, length).Shape()
    pipe_cylindert = BRepAlgoAPI_Fuse(cylinder, spheret)
    '''if pipe_cylindert.HasWarnings:
        print("construct error")'''
    #pipe_cylinderb = BRepAlgoAPI_Fuse(pipe_cylindert, sphereb).Shape()
    return pipe_cylindert.Shape()#tempfusedpipe.Shape() # adds cylinder an sphere together

def _cone_pipe(p1, p2, radius: float) -> TopoDS_Shape:
    length = get_magnitude(p1, p2) #gives vector p2 - p1 and then get the norm
    direction = get_direction(p1, p2) #gives normalised p2-p1 vector 
    axis = gp_Ax2(p1, direction) # creates coordinate system with an origin at p1, and z- axis pointed in "direction" (referes to z-axis as main direction I believe)
    return BRepPrimAPI_MakeCone(axis, 0.0, radius, length).Shape() # Cone made with height = length, bottom radius = 0, top radius =radius, on the axis as defined in the previous line


def down_to_end(p1: gp_Pnt, radius: float) -> TopoDS_Shape:
    p2 = gp_Pnt(p1.X(), p1.Y(), -1)
    direction = get_direction(p1, p2) #gives normalised p2-p1 vector
    length = get_magnitude(p1,p2)

    #cylinder = BRepOffsetAPI_MakePipe(guide_wire, profile).Shape() #I believe this makes the cylinder the around the "guild_wire" (which is just a line from p1 to p2) using the circle shape (profile) as the radius
    cylinder = BRepPrimAPI_MakeCylinder(gp_Ax2(p1, direction), radius, length).Shape()
    return cylinder#tempfusedpipe.Shape() # adds cylinder an sphere together
    



points_arrays = [[(-84.56448, -5.92066, 141.63786), (-97.93793, -3.85557, 101.72475), (-97.93793, -3.39292, 99.85594), (-97.93793, -2.79716, 97.92917), (-97.93793, -2.24472, 96.10507), (-97.93793, -1.46713, 94.26245)]]

decimals = 5

for i in range(len(points_arrays)):
    for j in range(len(points_arrays[i])):
        x = round(points_arrays[i][j][0],decimals)
        y = round(points_arrays[i][j][1],decimals)
        z = round(points_arrays[i][j][2],decimals)
        
        
        points_arrays[i][j] = gp_Pnt(x, y, z)

allpipes = None
for i, points in enumerate(points_arrays):
    radius = 1.5
    TIP_LENGTH = 2.5

    p1 = points[0]
    p2 = points[1]
    length = get_magnitude(p1, p2)
    if length < TIP_LENGTH:
        pipe = _cone_pipe(p1, p2, radius)
    else:
        vector = get_vector(p1, p2, length=TIP_LENGTH) #gives normalized vector if p2-p1 *TIP_LENGTH
        p_mid = gp_Pnt(p1.X() + vector.X(), p1.Y() +
                        vector.Y(), p1.Z() + vector.Z())
        cone = _cone_pipe(p1, p_mid, radius) #makes cone at end of needle
        pipe = _rounded_pipe(p_mid, p2, radius)
        pipe = BRepAlgoAPI_Fuse(cone, pipe).Shape()

    # rest of the points
    for i in range(1, len(points) - 1):
        p1 = points[i]
        p2 = points[i + 1]
        section = _rounded_pipe(p1, p2, radius)
        try:
            f2 = BRepAlgoAPI_Fuse()
            L1 = TopTools_ListOfShape()
            L1.Append(pipe)
            L2 = TopTools_ListOfShape()
            L2.Append(section)
            f2.SetArguments(L1)
            f2.SetTools(L2)
            f2.SetFuzzyValue(-0.001)
            f2.Build()
            #tempfuse = BRepAlgoAPI_Fuse(pipe, cylinder)
            if f2.HasWarnings():
                print("")
                print(i,"Grr")
                printpoint(points[i - 1])
                printpoint(p1)
                printpoint(p2)
                printpoint(points[i + 2])
                #del points[i]
            else:
                pipe = f2.Shape()
            #pipe = f2.Shape()
        except Exception as e:
            #print("Grrr" + str(e))
            print("")

    # if the points extend past z zero, don't extend
    if points[-1].Z() < 0:
        print()
    else:
        # extend out of cylinder
        extension_for_pipe = down_to_end(points[-1], radius)
        extended_pipe = BRepAlgoAPI_Fuse(pipe, extension_for_pipe).Shape()
        pipe = extended_pipe
    
    display.DisplayShape(pipe, update=True)

start_display()

as you can see here

there is a segment missing from the channel. I do not understand what is causing the issue
If the else statement is taken out from line 138 and the f2.Shape() has 1 indent removed from it to find the following
if f2.HasWarnings():
    print("")
    print(i,"Grr")
    printpoint(points[i - 1])
    printpoint(p1)
    printpoint(p2)
    printpoint(points[i + 2])
    #del points[i]
pipe = f2.Shape()

Then the error result in the whole top of the channel not being displayed
If anyone has any idea why this might be happening I would greatly appreciate any help


Okay, here is a partial answer. First thing that was done is removing collinear points using a function I did not write and so did not write and so cannot fairly post which fixed this issue, the function just went through the points comparing 3 at a time and if the three points were ~linearly related then the middle point would be removed (if I get permission to share the function I will). However, this did not fix everything so I wrote a few try except statements which are used to try and correct errors if warnings occur which fixed another error. For some needle channels an error still persists; however, this is the code which solves some of the issues;
from OCC.Core.BRepAlgoAPI import BRepAlgoAPI_Fuse
from OCC.Core.BRepBuilderAPI import BRepBuilderAPI_Transform
from OCC.Core.gp import gp_Vec, gp_Trsf
from OCC.Core.BRepPrimAPI import BRepPrimAPI_MakeCylinder, BRepPrimAPI_MakeTorus
from OCC.Core.gp import gp_Trsf
from OCC.Core.TopTools import TopTools_ListOfShape
from OCC.Display.SimpleGui import init_display

from OCC.Core.gp import gp_Pnt, gp_Ax2, gp_Dir
from OCC.Core.BRepPrimAPI import BRepPrimAPI_MakeCone, BRepPrimAPI_MakeSphere, BRepPrimAPI_MakeCylinder
from OCC.Core.TopoDS import TopoDS_Shape
from OCC.Core.TopTools import TopTools_ListOfShape

import numpy as np


display, start_display, add_menu, add_function_to_menu = init_display(size=(1500,1000))
display.EraseAll()

def printpoint(p1: gp_Pnt):
    print("("+str(p1.X())+","+str(p1.Y())+","+str(p1.Z())+")")

def get_vector(p1: gp_Pnt, p2: gp_Pnt, length: float = 1.0) -> gp_Vec:
    vector = gp_Vec(
        p2.X() - p1.X(),
        p2.Y() - p1.Y(),
        p2.Z() - p1.Z())
    return vector.Normalized() * length

def get_direction(p1: gp_Pnt, p2: gp_Pnt) -> gp_Dir:
    vector = get_vector(p1, p2) #p2-p1*length where p2 and p1 are vectors and length is 1 by default
    return gp_Dir(vector.X(), vector.Y(), vector.Z()) #gives normalized vector

def get_magnitude(p1: gp_Pnt, p2: gp_Pnt) -> float:
    vector = np.array([p2.X(), p2.Y(), p2.Z()]) \
        - np.array([p1.X(), p1.Y(), p1.Z()])
    return np.linalg.norm(vector)#np.linalg.norm (defaults to 2-norm)

def down_to_end(p1: gp_Pnt, radius: float) -> TopoDS_Shape:
    p2 = gp_Pnt(p1.X(), p1.Y(), -1)
    direction = get_direction(p1, p2) #gives normalised p2-p1 vector
    length = get_magnitude(p1,p2)

    cylinder = BRepPrimAPI_MakeCylinder(gp_Ax2(p1, direction), radius, length).Shape()
    return cylinder#tempfusedpipe.Shape() # adds cylinder an sphere together

def _rounded_pipe(p1: gp_Pnt, p2: gp_Pnt, radius: float) -> TopoDS_Shape:
    direction = get_direction(p1, p2) #gives normalised p2-p1 vector
    length = get_magnitude(p1,p2)

    sphere = BRepPrimAPI_MakeSphere(p2, radius).Shape()# makes a sphere centered at p2 and then makes it radius = radius
    cylinder = BRepPrimAPI_MakeCylinder(gp_Ax2(p1, direction), radius, length).Shape()
    pipe_cylinder = BRepAlgoAPI_Fuse(cylinder, sphere).Shape()
    return pipe_cylinder#tempfusedpipe.Shape() # adds cylinder an sphere together
    
def _cone_pipe(p1, p2, radius: float) -> TopoDS_Shape:
    length = get_magnitude(p1, p2) #gives vector p2 - p1 and then get the norm
    direction = get_direction(p1, p2) #gives normalised p2-p1 vector 
    axis = gp_Ax2(p1, direction) # creates coordinate system with an origin at p1, and z- axis pointed in "direction"
    return BRepPrimAPI_MakeCone(axis, 0.0, radius, length).Shape() # Cone made with height = length, bottom radius = 0, top radius =radius, on the axis as defined in the previous line

radius = 1.5
TIP_LENGTH = 2.5
decimals = 5

all_channel_points = [[[8.04134, -4.971, 130.87256], [7.96093, -4.90911, 130.17636], [7.89186, -4.84651, 129.57054], [7.81143, -4.79457, 128.87331], [7.82247, -4.78266, 128.27112]], 
[[1.42656, 2.4833, 150.37302], [1.35897, -2.06597, 140.25875], [1.2441, -8.64539, 123.05916], [1.20093, -9.65226, 117.48918]]]


for channel_points in all_channel_points:

    points = [gp_Pnt(point[0], point[1], point[2]) for point in channel_points]

    # generate starting point on top (cone)
    p1 = points[0]
    p2 = points[1]
    length = get_magnitude(p1, p2)
    if length < TIP_LENGTH:
        pipe = _cone_pipe(p1, p2, radius)
    else:
        vector = get_vector(p1, p2, length=TIP_LENGTH) #gives normalized vector of p2-p1 *TIP_LENGTH
        p_mid = gp_Pnt(p1.X() + vector.X(), p1.Y() +
                        vector.Y(), p1.Z() + vector.Z())
        cone = _cone_pipe(p1, p_mid, radius) #makes cone at end of needle
        pipe = _rounded_pipe(p_mid, p2, radius)
        pipe = BRepAlgoAPI_Fuse(cone, pipe).Shape()
        

    # rest of the points

    def fix1():
        cylinder = _rounded_pipe(p1, p2, radius+0.001)
        try:
            tempfuse = BRepAlgoAPI_Fuse(pipe, cylinder)
            if tempfuse.HasWarnings():
                return [0,tempfuse]
            return [1, tempfuse]
        except:
            return [-1, tempfuse]
        
    def fix2():
        max_attempt_value = -1#-1 if error, 0 if warning, 1 if success
        for i in [4,3,2]:
            #may introduce some rounding error (up to 0.01 can correct later if need be)
            p1.SetX(round(p1.X(),i))
            p1.SetY(round(p1.Y(),i))
            p1.SetZ(round(p1.Z(),i))
            p1.SetX(round(p1.X(),i))
            p1.SetY(round(p1.Y(),i))
            p1.SetZ(round(p1.Z(),i))
            cylinder = _rounded_pipe(p1, p2, radius)
            try:
                tempfuse = BRepAlgoAPI_Fuse(pipe, cylinder)
                if tempfuse.HasWarnings():
                    if(0>max_attempt_value):
                        max_attempt_value = 0
                else:
                    return [1, tempfuse]
            except:
                return [-1, tempfuse]
            return[max_attempt_value, tempfuse]
        
    def fix3():
        max_attempt_value = -1#-1 if error, 0 if warning, 1 if success
        tests = [[p1.SetX(p1.X()+0.01), p1.SetX(p1.X()-0.01)],
        [p1.SetY(p1.Y()+0.01), p1.SetY(p1.Y()-0.01)],
        [p1.SetZ(p1.Z()+0.01), p1.SetZ(p1.Z()+0.01)],
        [p1.SetX(p1.X()+0.01), p1.SetX(p1.X()+0.01)],
        [p1.SetY(p1.Y()+0.01), p1.SetY(p1.Y()+0.01)],
        [p1.SetZ(p1.Z()+0.01), p1.SetZ(p1.Z()+0.01)]]
        for item in tests:
            cylinder = _rounded_pipe(p1, p2, radius+0.001)
            item[0]
            try:
                tempfuse = BRepAlgoAPI_Fuse(pipe, cylinder)
                if tempfuse.HasWarnings():
                    if(0>max_attempt_value):
                        max_attempt_value=0
                        item[1]
                else:
                    item[1]
                    return [1, tempfuse]
            except:
                item[1]
                print('',end='')
        return [max_attempt_value, tempfuse]

    for i in range(1, len(points) - 1):
        p1 = points[i]
        p2 = points[i + 1]
        cylinder = _rounded_pipe(p1, p2, radius)
        try:
            tempfuse = BRepAlgoAPI_Fuse(pipe, cylinder)
            # print(tempfuse.HasErrors())
            if tempfuse.HasWarnings():
                fix = fix1()#tries adjusting the radius a bit (0.001)
                if(fix[0]==1):
                    tempfuse = fix[1]
                else:
                    fix = fix2()#tries rounding decimals =4,3,2
                    if(fix[0]==1):
                        tempfuse = fix[1]
                    else:
                        fix = fix3()#tries rounding decimals =4,3,2
                        if(fix[0]==1):
                            tempfuse = fix[1]
                        else:
                            printpoint(p1)
                            printpoint(p2)
                            print("warning sent while making 3d model of channel")
                
        except:
            fix = fix1()
            if(fix[0]==1 or fix[0] ==0):
                tempfuse = fix[1]
            else:
                fix = fix2()
                if(fix[0]==1 or fix[0] ==0):
                    tempfuse = fix[1]
                    if(fix[0] ==0):
                        printpoint(p1)
                        printpoint(p2)
                        print("warning sent while making 3d model of channel")
                else:
                    fix = fix3()
                    if(fix[0]==1 or fix[0] ==0):
                        tempfuse = fix[1]
                        if(fix[0] ==0):
                            printpoint(p1)
                            printpoint(p2)
                            print("warning sent while making 3d model of channel")
                    else:
                        printpoint(p1)
                        printpoint(p2)
                        print("loading channel to 3d display failed")

        pipe = tempfuse.Shape()
        display.DisplayShape(pipe, update=True)

start_display()

One persisting issue as shown in the second array in the all_channel_points array is that channel (which I have limited to the 4 points that cause the issue) is that the there is a section that does not appear; also, there is another example from a different file which causes a different error as well, but I do not have the points ready as of yet.
I realize this is not a complete answer, but I think it is a good start if someone has a similar issue
